# How can I setup a song request Icecast2 server that pulls songs from YouTube?

Tags: youtube, icecast

I would like to setup an Icecast2 server with a webpage for people to request songs by submitting YouTube links. I would also like submitted songs to be added to a queue as well. Is this even possible? I don't really know much about coding so if there is anything prebuilt that would be great! I mainly want to use this for my TS3 server so other people in the channel can request songs to play. Also, if I could convert the audio to mp3 format that would be great! Otherwise I can setup VLC to play the stream.

Edit: The server is running Windows 10 and uses IIS for public web content if that matters.

Comment: There are plenty of building blocks around to create such a thing. I'm not aware of a plug-and-play solution though. E.g. there's youtube-dl, which can download the audio track of youtube videos, also vlc can handle youtube URLs. You'd still need to piece everything together, etc.

Comment: @TBR I had no idea VLC could open regular YouTube URLs.  Now I can bypass their crappy smart TV players.  Thanks!